# Find and replace a string with incremental value in all files in a directory

Tags: xml, replace, awk, sed

I was able to replace in a file but incremental value is not coming correctly (adding line number) using awk command and also need to do for all [xml](/questions/tagged/xml) files in a directory.

```
awk '{ sub(/ID>NA/,"ID>NA"++n); print }' file1 >file1
```

`file.xml`:

```
<ID>NA</ID>
<Subject>ASDF</Subject>
 ...
<ID>NA</ID>
<Subject>ASDF</Subject>
...
<ID>NA</ID>
<Subject>ASDF</Subject>
...
<ID>NA</ID>
<Subject>ASDF</Subject>
```

Expected Result is:

`file1.xml`:

```
<ID>NA1</ID>
<Subject>ASDF</Subject>
...
<ID>NA2</ID>
<Subject>ASDF</Subject>
...
<ID>NA3</ID>
<Subject>ASDF</Subject>
...
<ID>NA4</ID>
<Subject>ASDF</Subject>
```

Comment: Please replace all of the `...` lines with actual sample data such that you have something we can test a potential solution against. You must NEVER do `command file > file` as the shell can execute the `> file` part before executing the `command file` part and if so it would overwrite `file` before `command` opens it for reading. Do `command file > tmp && mv tmp file` instead. You say you want to add line number but your command and expected output do not do that, they add instance number of "NA" - which do you want?

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you want:

```
for file in *
do
    awk '{ sub(/ID>NA/,"ID>NA"++n); print }' "$file" > tmp &&
    mv tmp "$file"
done
```

but it's not 100% clear from your question. With GNU awk 4.* you could abbreviate the above to:

```
awk -i inplace '{ sub(/ID>NA/,"ID>NA"++n); print }' "$file"
```

Comment: Thank you Ed and John, It is working for default value 'NA' using awk '/VehicleID>NA/{sub(/VehicleID>NA/,"VehicleID>NA"++n)}; 1' as expected.  awk -i inplace is not working. I think we don't have right version on our system.  Is it possible to search and replace incremental value based on dynamic value in ID element. Actually I came to know NA is not default value.

Comment: You can write the code to do whatever you want but you'll have to edit your question to state your new requirements with sample input and expected output. It might be best for you to start over with a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You were incrementing `n` with every line.  From the sample output, it appears that you only want to increment `n` on lines for which the substitution is made.  In that case:

```
$ awk '/ID>NA/{ sub(/ID>NA/,"ID>NA"++n)}; 1' file1.xml
<ID>NA1</ID>
<Subject>ASDF</Subject>
...
<ID>NA2</ID>
<Subject>ASDF</Subject>
...
<ID>NA3</ID>
<Subject>ASDF</Subject>
...
<ID>NA4</ID>
<Subject>ASDF</Subject>
```

Also, `awk ... file > file` does not work for changing a file in place.  Use

```
$ awk '/ID>NA/{ sub(/ID>NA/,"ID>NA"++n)}; 1' file1.xml >tmp && mv tmp file1.xml
```

With GNU awk, this can be simplified. To change all xml files in the directory in place at once:

```
awk -i inplace '/ID>NA/{ sub(/ID>NA/,"ID>NA"++n)}; 1' *.xml
```